# Feed to select from mysql db through Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following Code

```
if($('#b_ID').length==1){
                $('#gen, #dob').change(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?=APP_PATH?>ajax/json.class.php",
                        data: {
                            gen: $('#gen').val()
                            ,dob: $('#dob').val()
                        },
                    }).done(function( msg ) {
                        var wcs = $.parseJSON(msg);
                        console.log(wcs);
                        $('#b_ID').html('');
                        $('#b_ID').append('<option value="">'+'<?=_('[Select]')?>'+'</option>');
                        $.each(wcs, function(){
                            $wc=$(this);
                            //check for original value
                            var selected = $('#orig_ID').val()==$wc[0].ID_w?' selected="selected"':'';

                            $('#b_ID').append('<option '+selected+' value="'+$wc[0].ID_w+'">'+$wc[0].w_d+'</option>');

                        })
                    })      

                })
            }
```

The above code is working perfect, if the form is loaded from other previous form. For example,

form1.php contains two fields 
dob text input
select option

After we insert dob and select from option, when I save and then I load the second form which contains the select option that depends on those two inputs. For this purpose it works OK.

but what I need is I have all the elements on the form, all three fields, including one input and two select, so according to the first input of dob and the second select, I want to fill the third selection.

How could I change the above code to be able to work?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you need, exactly. Do you need an entirely new form that contains gen, dob, and all the contents of the new `<select>`? Or do you need more than that?

Comment: No, What i need is I have all the element on the form, all three fields, including one input and two select, so according to the first input of dob and the second select, i want to fill the third selection, but the above code i have given seems not working...what is the error?

Comment: in other word, how do i fill the third select according to the first two given data? first one dob input and second one is select option...why the above code not working???

Comment: Does your debugger tell you anything useful? Like is the code in `$.each()` actually running? And what HTML does the debugger show you after that code runs? If you can't get any clues from the debugger, post your code in a fiddle to demonstrate the problem.